# What is the partial red in dot top left of screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

What is the partial red in dot top left of screen? I started seeing this the other day. At first I thought there was something broken now I think it has something to do with notifications. Anyone know the logic behind this?

[image: weird red dot]

Comment: I think it's a bug. You should report it to Apple, so they can fix it. https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: Is your iPhone jailbroken?  You said you started seeing it "the other day".  Did you install something recently or make any system changes?

Comment: That screenshot doesn't look like any version of iOS that I'm familiar with. You might want to tell us more about your setup.

Comment: I'm running IOS 11.2,2. Not jailbroken. It's an iPhone X. Didn't install anything new in the last month.

Comment: I have it too, did you ever figure out what it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting my phone fixed the problem. Turns out it's related to the way you close windows with the iPhone X. Has anyone seen this that doesn't have an iPhone X?

Comment: What's up with 2500 views and no upvotes? help a hacker out.